# Configuring AWS Lambda to access S3 Bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, bucket, amazon-policy

I just can't figure out what is wrong with my **Bucket Policy** in AWS. Trying to let a Lambda function to access and read an email from the S3 Bucket. But I keep getting **"Access Denied"**

Please note that I notice the email file is being created in the bucket. Here is my last version of the **Bucket Policy**:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Id": "Lambda access bucket policy",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "All on objects in bucket lambda",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::[MY NUMBER]:root"
            },
            "Action": "s3:GetObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::[MY BUCKET NAME]/*"
        }
    ]
}
```

I have tried also with "Principal": {"Service": "ses.amazonaws.com"}, alas

I keep getting **Access Denied**:

```
2017-09-17T14:12:14.231Z 10664101-9bb2-11e7-ad43-539f3e1a8626
{
    "errorMessage": "Access Denied",
    "errorType": "AccessDenied",
    "stackTrace": [
        "Request.extractError (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/services/s3.js:577:35)",
        "Request.callListeners (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:105:20)",
        "Request.emit (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:77:10)",
        "Request.emit (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:683:14)",
        "Request.transition (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:22:10)",
        "AcceptorStateMachine.runTo (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/state_machine.js:14:12)",
        "/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/state_machine.js:26:10",
        "Request.<anonymous> (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:38:9)",
        "Request.<anonymous> (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:685:12)",
        "Request.callListeners (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:115:18)"
    ]
}
```

And here is my **Lambda function**:

```
var AWS = require('aws-sdk');
var s3 = new AWS.S3();

var bucketName = '[MY BUCKET NAME]';

exports.handler = function(event, context, callback) {
    console.log('Process email');

    var sesNotification = event.Records[0].ses;
    if(!sesNotification) {
        callback(null, null);
        return;
    }

    console.log("SES Notification:\n", JSON.stringify(sesNotification, null, 2));

    // Retrieve the email from your bucket
    s3.getObject({
            Bucket: bucketName,
            Key: sesNotification.mail.messageId
        }, function(err, data) {
            if (err) {
                console.log(err, err.stack);
                callback(err);
            } else {
                console.log("Raw email:\n" + data.Body);

                // Custom email processing goes here

                callback(null, null);
            }
        });
};
```

After long time and many versions of the **Bucket Policy** I am thinking of trying another solution and drop AWS.

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to create an IAM role and attach it to the Lambda function with `S3FullAccess` policy or with finegrained permission for the specific bucket and actions (Recommended).

Also make sure trust relationship configuration is added to the role.

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Action": "sts:AssumeRole",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "Service": [
          "lambda.amazonaws.com"
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Note: In your current setup, it seems like you have configured the bucket policy which grants read access to the root user.

Comment: thanks for the answer. I have created an IAM user with fullS3Access. Yet I couldn't find where I attach it to the Lambda function nor where can I add it to the S3 Bucket ...

Comment: You need to create an IAM role instead of a user and also add the trust relationships for Lambda inside the role (Apart from the policy). Check the updated answer

Comment: Did both. Still get "Access Denied". What should be my Policy Bucket Principal ?

Comment: For testing purposes. First remove the bucket policy you added from S3. Create a iam role with s3 full access and with the mentioned trust relationship. Then attach the role to lambda and tryout?

Comment: Thanks. Now I get "The specific key does not exist" which is another problem :-)

Comment: please update the answer regarding attaching the S3FullAccess to the Lambda Role and I will set is the chosen answer.

Comment: I have updated the answer. Also mote that for security it is recommended to whitelist the specific bucket resource and actions within the policy.